# Realizar cálculos matemáticos com valores de uma tabela dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Possuo uma tabela em form-wizard que assim que clico em "adicionar item" chamo uma função e ela adiciona uma linha na tabela para adicionar um novo item a ser comprado pelo cliente.

Esta tabela que a cada clique adiciona um item possui uma função autocompletar no campo "Titulo" no qual busca os valores de "Código","Valor Unitário" e "Quantidade disponível" no banco de dados e preenche automaticamente estes campos que estão em "disabled" conforme estão na foto acima.

O input "Quantidade Vendida" deve ser inserido manualmente pelo usuário.

Segue a imagem abaixo do trecho citado acima:

[image: tabela]

Logo abaixo tenho inputs em que se adiciona o desconto e outro que deveria mostrar o valor total da venda baseado nas informações acima.

Segue imagem:

[image: tabela]

Meu problema é que não consigo realizar o cálculo para saber o valor total. Este cálculo deve ser baseado no valor unitário e quantidade vendida de cada item.

Se fosse um número estático de itens eu saberia, mas como a cada clique no botão "adicionar item" faz com que gere novos valores como eu faço para calcular o valor total?

Código da função que autocompleta e adiciona os valores aos inputs disabled:

```
<script id="teste" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var cnt = 1;
    var quantidadedisponivel;     

$("#adicionar_item").click(function(){

    $('#tabela_publicacoes tr').last().after('<tr><td>'+cnt+'</td><td><input type="hidden" name="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" id="titulopublicacao'+cnt+'" style="width: 500px;"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="cod_publicacao'+cnt+'" id="cod_publicacao'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled"></td><td><input class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="valorunitario'+cnt+'" id="valorunitario'+cnt+'" type="text" value="0" onChange="Calcular_ValorTotal(this.form)"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" id="quantidadedisponivel'+cnt+'" type="text" disabled="disabled" value=""></td><td><input class="form-control" name="quantidadevendida'+cnt+'" id="quantidadevendida'+cnt+'" type="text" value="0" onChange="Calcular_ValorTotal(this.form)"></td></tr>');      

        $('#titulopublicacao'+cnt).select2({
            placeholder: "Digite o título da Publicacao",
            ajax: {         
                url: 'autosuggest_busca_publicacao.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    var results = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        results.push({
                            text: item.titulopublicacao + " - Número: " + item.numero + " - Ano: " + item.ano,
                            id: item.cod_publicacao,
                            cod_publicacao: item.cod_publicacao,
                            valorunitario: item.valorunitario,
                            quantidadedisponivel: item.quantidadedisponivel
                        });
                    });
                    return { results: results }
                }
            },
        }).on("change", change);    

    function change(el) {           
        var id = $(this).parent().prev('td').text();    
        var data = $(el.target).select2('data');            
        var cod_publicacao = data.cod_publicacao;
        var valorunitario = data.valorunitario;
        var quantidadedisponivel = data.quantidadedisponivel;
        var input = $(el.target).closest('tr').find('input[name="cod_publicacao'+id+'"]').last().val(cod_publicacao);
        var input2 = $(el.target).closest('tr').find('input[name="valorunitario'+id+'"]').last().val(valorunitario);
        var input3 = $(el.target).closest('tr').find('input[name="quantidadedisponivel'+id+'"]').last().val(quantidadedisponivel); 
    } 

    cnt++;

    function formatoptions(results) {   
        return results.text;
    }           

});

$("#remover_item").click(function(){
    if($('#tabela_publicacoes tr').size()>1){
        $('#tabela_publicacoes tr:last-child').remove();
    }else{
        alert('Erro, não foi possível remover');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa de uma função para chamar sempre que um valor é mudado. Qualquer coisa como:

```
function recalcular() {
    var somatorio = 0;
    var linhas = $('#tabela_publicacoes tr');
    linhas.each(function () {
        somatorio += $(this).find('input[name^="valorunitario"]').val() * $(this).find('input[name^="quantidadevendida"]').val();
    })
    $('#total').val(somatorio);
}
```

A ideia é ter um event handler como este exemplo:

```
$('#tabela_publicacoes').on('change', 'input', recalcular);
```

que dispare a função a cada mudança. Dentro da função exemplo que coloquei, a ideia é percorrer cada `tr` procurando os dois campos. Como você não sabe qual o numero deles, pode uar `^=` para dizer ao jQuery que o nome começa com essa string.

E aí é só somar essas multiplicações e colocar o valor onde deve estar com `$('#total').val(somatorio);`

A razão de eu usar delegação no `.on()` é que assim ele fica ligado à tabela. Se estivesse `$('#tabela_publicacoes tr')` então as novas linhas que iam sendo criadas não seriam checadas.

Comment: @Chico, tinha esquecido da outra função `change` que você já tem. Assim pode colocar este código dentro dela, ou chamar esta função `recalcular` de dentro da outra, no final.

Comment: então estou recebendo como retorno o NaN. 

Utilizo o .parseInt() em 

     $(this).find('input[name^="valorunitario"]').val() * $(this).find('input[name^="quantidadevendida"]').val(); ?

Comment: @Chico, teste isto: `var vUnit = $(this).find('input[name^="valorunitario"]').val(); alert(typeof vUnit + ' - ' + vUnit);` O que lhe dá?

Comment: retorna no alert: undefined - undefined

Comment: @Chico, está  pôr isso dentro do `each()`? Pode fazer também `console.log(linhas);`, está defenido?

Comment: primeiro alert dá undefined - undefined e depois logo em seguida surge outro alert escrito "string - 5.7(valorunitario)"

, coloquei dentro do each

Comment: @Chico, ok, e onde está a dar `NaN`? pode fazer o mesmo com o input `quantidadevendida`? Note que eu inventei esse `quantidadevendida` não sei se ele tem esse nome... tem?

Comment: O nome é "quantidadevendida" mesmo e acontece a mesma coisa para ele, primeiro alert "undefined-undefined" e em seguida "string - 2(que é a quantidade inserida no input)"

O NaN aparece no campo $('#valortotal').val(somatorio);. No input do valor total.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15364/discussion-between-sergio-and-chico).

Comment: @Chico, pode clicar no link do chat em cima? ^